# What information can be drawn from the area between the warping function and the diagonal path in DTW?

Tags: r, time-series

I'm using the R package [dtw: Dynamic Time Warping Algorithms](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtw/index.html) to study the similarity of two time series. This package provides also the possibility to estimate the area between the warping function and the diagonal (no-warping) path, in unit steps (function `warpArea`). I found an interesting application of this quantity in the following paper [Latency as a region contrast: Measuring ERP latency differences with Dynamic Time Warping](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/psyp.12521): a positive distance, which results from the warping path being below the diagonal, indicates that the reference time series, used for alignment, precedes the query time series, while a negative indicates that the reference time series follows the query.

What other information can be drawn from the area between the warping function and the diagonal path?